# Access environment variable in a korn shell script

Tags: scripting

my dev/qa/uat/prod servers each have an environmental variable "DATADIR".
For example in a dev linux server:

> echo $DATADIR
> devl

Can I access that environment variable inside
a korn shell script?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after reading more about variables.
System variables are available inside the script.

echo $SOMEPATH
/usr/bin/

path=$SOMEPATH
echo The path you want is $path

The path you want is /usr/bin